# How is it possible for threatmetrix to detect VPN?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, confidentiality

[Threatmetrix](http://www.threatmetrix.com/technology/proxy-and-vpn-detection/) is a fraud prevention SaaS aimed at preventing fraud. Their company website states:

> ThreatMetrix is also uniquely able to uncover hackers and fraudsters trying to cover their true location by hiding behind VPN servers. ThreatMetrix has developed a unique VPN detection capability that:
>
> - Captures additional TCP/IP packet header attributes
> - Analyzes the network connection type from an originating device, such as Ethernet, 3G, WiFi, VPN and others
> - Enables new sets of policies and alerts for fraud prevention
> - Distinguishes between normal IPs and VPN based IP addresses

I am interested in understanding: how is it possible to identify a user is using a VPN from the packet headers? How is it possible to detect the network connection type from originating device?

Comment: If this is being marked as duplicate, could we please at least move the answers over to the old question as the answers here seem much better...